# Is it possible to access the DOM inside an opened javascript window?

Tags: javascript

With javascript, I can open and close a popup window as follows.

```
var myWindow = window.open('http://example.org/');
// do things to window.
myWindow.close();
```

How do I manipulate the DOM elements of the page in the popup window before closing it? I have tried

```
myWindow.onready = function() {
    myWindow.document.getElementById('someElementID').style.color = '#f00';
}
```

to no avail.

Comment: @KashifNaseem Apparently, he is not trying to access the first window from the second, but the elements of the popup window.

Comment: There is no `onready` method on a window object.  You can access the DOM in a popup if it's the same domain.

Comment: Are both pages within the same domain?

Comment: You can use myWindow.onload instead of myWindow.onready

Comment: @jfriend00 Why does domain matter here?

Comment: @ATOzTOA Domain and even subdomain matter.

Comment: @ATOzTOA - iframes, frames and windows all require same-origin to access from elsewhere.  See details [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  It's so you can't spoof/manipulate content from other domains even if you created the window or frame.

Comment: Then how are we able to manipulate it through Firebug / Chrome JS Console?

Comment: How do I make it same domain if I am loading from local filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no event to let you know that the URL was loaded properly in the popup window. Only viable option is to set a timeout and then access the elements.

Like this:

```
var myWindow = window.open('./t6.html');  

setTimeout(check, 3000);

console.log($('body', myWindow.document)); // This shows a blank "body"

function check() {
    console.log($('body', myWindow.document)); // This shows the actual elements in the document
}

myWindow.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure document.getElementById works, when document is not even loaded?

Comment: You have to wait for the doc to be loaded.  And, you have to be the same domain.

Comment: Then, what about this? http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus

Comment: This answer won't work... seems like I am missing something. `myWindow.onload` does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3FG5/) that demonstrates it working without your ready handler.

```
var myWindow = window.open('http://example.org/');
alert(myWindow)
// Alerts an HTMLDocument object
```

Like @jfriend00 mentioned in the comments, there's no ready event handler for a [Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work... just that alert shows HTMLDocument doesn't mean it is an active window.